# Firebase flutter fetch multitipe data from collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a app.

At the moment I'm trying to get multitype data's from multitype collection.

**My Firebase construction:**
-user -user_id -data -product_data -product_id -product_details -product_details

**Example path:**
/user/SRufTqSjHFYiXdzHTSuO1aWsjip1/data/product_data
/id_1630254604523_SRufTqSjHFYiXdzHTSuO1aWsjip1/product_details

[image: Here an example:]

Now i try to get all 'product_details' from my products.

After that i would like to show all products from every user in my app.

There can be several products.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to fetch all 'product_details' for all products, 'product_details' has to be a collection (then you can use collectionGroups to fetch all data). In your present data, product_details is a document.

This is your present data structure:

> -user -user_id -data -product_data -product_id -product_details -data

You could restructure it to something like this:

> -user -user_id -data -product_data -product_details -product_id -data

NB: I changed the position of product_details and product_id. Product details now contains the details of all products. You can do the same thing for product_images.

Then you could fetch all product_details like this:

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionGroup =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('product_details');
QuerySnapshot query = await collectionGroup.get();
// above query will fetch all product_details for all users.
// if you want to fetch the all product_details for a particular user,
// then you have to add user_id to the product_details and use below
QuerySnapshot query =
    await collectionGroup.where('user_id', isEqualTo: 'user_id').get();
```

NB: This might require some indexes.

Comment: Hello @Peter thx for your aswer.
Im trying your example. 
It seems to work, but i can't get the data.
Im try to print it in console 'print('query: ' + query.toString());'

But i get only this output: 
I/flutter (12761): query: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

Maybe you can give me a example how i get the data from the collection (print).
Many thx.

Comment: I am guessing that what you are printing in query. Instead do this: print(query.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList());

Comment: The above will return a list of the product_details.

Comment: Hello @Peter thx for your fast answer.
Im trying your idea.
Now im getting this 'I/flutter (13280): query: [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']'.

Your code im trying:
getAllUserID() async{
   Query<Map<String, dynamic>>  collectionGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('product_details');
    //QuerySnapshot query = await collectionGroup.get();
    var query = await collectionGroup.get();
    print('query: ' + query.docs.toString());
}
Maybe you can help me, how i get the product details inside 'product_details.
Thx (:

Comment: You are a god. Now i can keep working. That's what I wanted. Many thx, Man.